# OpenMeetings install hangs in CentOS 5.6

Tags: video-streaming, centos, video-conferencing, openmeetings

After following [this](http://code.google.com/p/openmeetings/wiki/InstallationCentOS5) guide on installing OpenMeetings in CentOS 5.6, I've managed to install all dependencies, starting all proceses and configuring all software prior to the installation. I can actually **start** the installation but when I click "Install" I receive a blank screen in the step 1, and it drops dead.

The database does not populate with tables or data (and it should at this point), what makes me believe that I can't connect to the database.

I'm running MySQL 5.1.56, Red5 1.0, and OpenMeetings 1.7. I've copied the MySQL 5 hibernate to hibernate.conf.xml (using localhost). Assigned TCP/IP permissions to MySQL and the OpenMeetings user in the database (and I've tested the connections). All ports in the firewall are open (for testing). Every program needed is in the PATH variable. All dependencies are installed.

When accessing to `http://address:5080/openmeetings` I get the following error: http://cl.ly/9zDe

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to contact:
http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/mail-lists.html

Comment: Didn't know about those mailing lists — I expect that those are more active that their forums or such.

Comment: yes and I think they are discussing CentOS installation currently. There are some scripts in the www currently but nothing official.